# Extract certain text from cell in excel based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the image below, what I am trying to do is find a formula that would take certain text within the cell with a commonality of **Loreum impsum sabada** and extract that out into a separate cell ("To Be Extracted" column), but includes everything after once it ends in a period of the sentence.

Is there a way to do this through a formula?

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is.  One way would be to use `SEARCH` to determine where the string starts. Then use `SEARCH` again to find the first `period` after.  Then you can use the `MID` function to extract the relevant substring.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld can you please provide an example of how this would be structured from a formula perspective?

Comment: This is not a free "code-for-me" site. I suggest you go ahead and try it yourself. There are numerous examples on this and other forums of extracting substrings from strings using this technique.  Then edit your post to show what you have tried, if you still have problems. Or post it as an answer it if works.

Comment: It's not perfect, but I tried doing the following, and actually works out OK, but looking for something better -- see my answer below:

`=TRIM(MID(Z425,SEARCH($AC$1,Z425)+LEN($AC$1),50))`

Comment: You just need to replace the `50` with another search for the `period`.  Have that search `start_num` argument be the result of the first search(repeat the formula for that argument), and use the difference between the two for your `num_chars` argument of the `MID` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,SEARCH("Lorem",A1),1000),SEARCH(".",MID(A1,SEARCH("Lorem",A1),1000)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this but I was just working on something quite similar and couldn't resist.

In Cell `H2:` "One day I went to the park to buy bananas. **Your string** was watching me pat the blue and pink dog. Pity he didn’t know we drove cars"

Formula:

```
=MID(H2,SEARCH("Your string ",H2,1),SEARCH(".",MID(H2,FIND("Your string",H2,1),10000)))
```

I doubt you have a sentence in any language that is over 10000 characters in length. But if you do adjust the 10000 to something larger.

Output:  **Your string** was watching me pat the blue and pink dog.

Comment: Things would get much more complex if your string appeared in more than one sentence within a cell. Do they ? And would require multi extraction VBA or array fornula to extract the sentences. But for the simple example you've given, this suffices

Comment: Regex. If it did . Pattern recognition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but I tried doing the following, and actually works out OK, but looking for something better that gets to the intent of the question / problem I have -- extract the "Loreum impsum sabada" + characters afterward until it ends in a period.

`=TRIM(MID(Z425,SEARCH($AC$1,Z425)+LEN($AC$1),50))`

[image]